# How to make php file show in browser

Tags: php, html

I have an html file called enter.html and php file called form.php .My php file does not contain any html tag. And I posted my form infos through post method php proceeds it but php file does not show in browser . It directly downloads itsel automatically.Why? But If I take php scripts into html tag the file shows in browser.

Comment: then your server is misconfigured and isn't executing php.

Comment: Are you using a server or just opening the file in your browser??

Comment: or you are clicking on the file rather than going to the server's url, like `http://localhost/whatever.php`

Comment: I presume the OP doesn't have installed Apache Server and PHP...which OS are you using??

Comment: no no my server works well.I can view php script results in my browser.But in form example php script processes my infos but it does not appear in browser automatically downloads itself.

Comment: it si related about directory

Comment: I use xampp and now for practicing I am working in another file in htdocs

Answer (score 1):

This might be usefull.

Is your server turned on?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php